# Bind custom control to NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

I've subclassed `NSTextField` to create a custom control, and I want to bind a property (which is an `NSArray`) of my custom control to an `NSArrayController`. However I don't know how to propagate the array from my control to the `NSArrayController`. The key-path I'm using on the `NSArrayController` is `arrangedObjects.name`. For example, if I'm trying to propagate the array `(@"One", @"Two", @"Three")` and I simply use:

```
[boundObject setValue:myArray forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name"]
```

it will set the value of each element of `arrangedObjects.name` to the array `(@"One", @"Two", @"Three")`. What I want to happen is to have the first element in `arrangedObjects.name` set to `@"One"`, the second value set to `@"Two"`, etc.

NSTableColumn does this, so I know it's possible, but I can't figure out how it is implemented.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more information about your new custom property. Please elaborate.

Comment: It's simply an `NSArray*` called `customContent` (for lack of a better name) that's KVO compliant. I want to be able to bind it to an `NSArrayController` (bi-directionally). But all I really need to be able to do I guess is to set the `arrangedObjects.name` key-path correctly (as described above) on the `NSArrayController`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I think I may have answered my own question. I won't mark it as the correct answer right away in case someone can tell me a better way to do this. This way is pretty much a hack.

Anyway, I was reading about NSArrayController here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSArrayController which says:

> If `valueForKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name"` is sent to an array controller, one (as expected) gets back an array of name values, but if another object replicates this behaviour, and the table column's value is instead bound to this object, it will display the entire array for each row.

and

> You bind the value of an `NSTableColumn` to `arrangedObjects.someKey`. If you try to programmatically invoke `valueForKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.someKey"` on your array controller, you'll get back the array resulting from invoking `valueForKey:@"someKey"` on the `arrangedObjects` array -- this is all fine. So one would think that `NSTableColumn`'s value can also be bound to my objects `someArray.someKey`, but this will not work (on several levels).

So basically it sounds like `NSTableColumn` special cases its bindings for `NSArrayController` and `arrangedObjects` which is why it works the right way, and my custom control doesn't.

This doesn't seem very flexible, but it's the only way I can find to make it actually work. I implemented a special case in my bindings for NSArrayController and arrangedObjects and I was able to make it work like I wanted.

A better solution would be much appreciated, though!

Comment: Without knowing more about the implementation I would say that it sounds wrong to be storing an array in an NSTextField. Normally content would be stored and managed by a controller. The textfield should simply be a conduit for that content between the user and the controller. For example, let's say that I have an NSTextField and I ask the user to input a series of comma separated values (i.e., a basic array). I would have a controller that take the string from the text field and then parse and store the content in the controller.